# Store Twitter and Facebook API credentials

Tags: php, facebook, cordova, twitter

I am working on PhoneGap app where user login and map there twitter and facebook account with one core user account.

So basically I am looking for functionality in which when user log's in back there twitter and facebook would me already mapped to perform further actions.

How can I store above credentials of facebook and Twitter API in database. I am using PHP & MySQL in back-end. What exact Oauth credentials we need to store? I am using Javascript for login.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for creating OAuth was to prevent the third parties from accessing the confidential information of the users like password and other things. You cannot get the users credentials from those sites and store in your database.

Comment: Access token I get right? SO how can I reuse same token to fire queries? And whats the difference between https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize and https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authenticate

Comment: Why do you want to store the tokens when they get changed for every login?

Comment: How about I use same Oauth token to fire queries that I achieved while login? I guess If I use same I can perform actions. I wont login every time.

Comment: for that start session flag, once the user successfully logs in then set that session flag variable to true, until the user logs out, i.e session is destroyed.

Comment: But then if user logs in again will I be able to retrieve x facebook and twitter tokens? And do you have idea how Hootsuits works? I am looking for similar functionality

Comment: when the user will login again he will get a new token you do not need to worry about that, and i do not know Hootsuits works.